# Can a remote server access my local resources when using remote desktop?

Tags: windows, security, remote-desktop

I do support work and I use remote desktop to connect to different servers around the world. I share my local resources in remote desktop to easily be able to get files from my local computer.

However, is it possible for someone at the server end to get access to my local files through the remote desktop session? My local files show up as mapped network drives on the server.

Comment: Please tag the name of your operating system when asking operating system dependent questions, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

If you map your local disks to the server then yes, if they wanted to.